# Max open files per process limit - linux kernel

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel

There seems to be a hardcoded upper limit on the maximum open file descriptors (process limit) of 1048576 is that correct?

Incase this has changed recently, my version:

```
Linux mq981 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 13:41:29 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
```

You can change it by writing to that file, it's not hardcoded.

The actual upper limit you can set it to is much [larger](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc4/source/fs/file.c#L29).

Comment: Hey, that is funny; different types of integer for more or less the same.

Comment: What's funny? On a 32bit platform, `INT_MAX` pointers ((2^31 - 1) * 4) is larger than `SIZE_MAX` and won't fit into an array.

Comment: what is line 25 saying?

Comment: How?
```
sudo echo 2000000 > /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
-bash: /proc/sys/fs/nr_open: Permission denied
```

Comment: @guesty try `sudo sh -c 'echo 2000000 > /proc/sys/fs/nr_open'`. (There may be simpler ways, but I'm not using sudo, ever). Your command fails because it's your shell (running as a *regular user*) which handles any redirections and tries to open that file BEFORE running the `sudo` command.

Comment: @PeterPrographo it sets the default of `sysctl_nr_open` to `1024*1024`. `__read_mostly` probably expands to some GCC attribute supposed to optimize the code by informing the compiler, loader, etc that that variable will be rarely (if ever) updated (in practice, it's probably just grouping it into some section with other such variables for annotation purposes). As you'll see if you click on it, that elixir site doesn't really know how to parse C, and wrongly considers `__read_mostly` a *variable*, too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It is not so hard coded as you state. The maximum number for your system is

```
 cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

For me, that would be 3257198. If you are adventurous (changing kernel parameters on the fly, mmmmmm), you can change that number.

The absolute maximum is given by the fact that this is a `long` integer in C, and the maximum would therefore be 2147483647.

On a per process basis, the maximum is

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
```

(on my system also your 1048576).

Technically, this is an unsigned long (see `fs.h`; search for `unsigned long max_files;` in the `struct files_stat_struct`. But, your number of open files per process must be below the system-wide maximum, so it should be below 2147483647 or below your  `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` vaule.

Comment: That's the per-system, not the per-process limit. Go read `Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.rst`

Comment: It's not true that the nr. of files opened by a process should be below `sys-max`. It's both that multiple file descriptors can refer to the same file handle and that privileged processes are not subject to that `sys-max` limit. That limit is completely irrelevant in the context of this question.